# Reading documents with r-tm to use with r-mallet

Tags: tm, mallet, tidytext

I have this code to fit a topic model with the [R wrapper for MALLET](https://github.com/mimno/RMallet):

```
docs <- mallet.import(DF$document, DF$text, stop_words)

mallet_model <- MalletLDA(num.topics = 4)
mallet_model$loadDocuments(docs)
mallet_model$train(100)
```

I have used the [tm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/versions/0.6-2) package to read my documents, which are txt files in a directory:

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(DirSource("data")) # a directory of txt files
```

The corpus can't be used as input for `mallet.import`, so how do I get from the tm corpus `myCorpus` above to the `DF` to call upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tidy data principles to process your text and get it ready for input into mallet, with one row per document, [as described here](http://tidytextmining.com/topicmodeling.html#alternative-lda-implementations).

Also, there are tidiers for the [mallet package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mallet) in tidytext, and you can use them to analyze the output of mallet topic modeling:

```
# word-topic pairs
tidy(mallet_model)

# document-topic pairs
tidy(mallet_model, matrix = "gamma")

# column needs to be named "term" for "augment"
term_counts <- rename(word_counts, term = word)
augment(mallet_model, term_counts)
```

Answer (score 2):

RMallet is intended to be a standalone package, so integration with tm isn't great. The requirement for RMallet input is a data frame with one row per document, and a character field containing the text, which it expects to not be tokenized already.